# Eclipse is unable to resolve these classes, like AbstractProjectDescriptor in jenkins-core-xxx.jar

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Below error messages in Eclipse blocked me from developing a jenkins plugin like forever

Eclipse is unable to resolve these 3 classes :

- hudson.model.AbstractProject.AbstractProjectDescriptor
- hudson.model.Queue.Task
- hudson.model.Queue.Item

There could be more. But in *jenkins-core-1.554.1-sources.jar*, I did found the relevant class source code.

Anyway, it runs pretty ok under `CLI` startup `mvn hpi:run`

Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

Well, after googling around, I've found the answer this question in a [google forum topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-dev/4rvorfnry1w).

**Reason:**

```
I could confirm it is definitely the bridge method injector which is causing the issue.

In Queue.Item, there is the following getter annotated

@WithBridgeMethods(Future.class)
public QueueTaskFuture getFuture() { return future; }

Removing the annotation then recompiling core fixes the issue for this class.

Also, depending on a jenkins-core that is in the workspace workarounds the issue 
(because then the bridge method injector isn't called by JDT)
```

I did try that out and it worked!

**Workaroud:**

1. Download the source.zip from https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins

> I mean the root of the project, pick out any commit, branch or release as you wish like https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/releases
>
> Unzip this source.zip to folder `jenkins-xxx` (wherever as you like)
>
> Regular replace via any kind of text editor of your choice,  replacing `@WithBridgeMethods\(.*\)` with `// patching for debug`  to `jenkins-xxx/core/src/**/*.java`
>
> Run `mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true` (you should get your maven working) under `jenkins-xxx`
>
> Replace this `jenkins-core-xxx.jar` in your project classpath
>
> **Note:** 
>   some error may occur on other modules, it won't matter if `jenkins-core-xxx.jar` is finally built out

Hope this work for you.